# Dúvida sobre array PHP

Tags: php, array

Estou com uma dúvida quanto a separar um conteúdo de um arquivo texto e separar por `array`.

Por exemplo, tenho os seguintes textos:

```
TEXTO1
<head> <edic><Diário Gaúcho 12/05/2013</edic>
<autor>Denise Waskow, denise.waskow@diariogaucho.com.br</autor>
</head>
<body>
<subtítulo>Para celebrar</subtítulo>
<título>Mães e filhos se divertem em atividades culturais no Parque da Redenção</título>
Jogos de mesa, futebol, brinquedos infláveis, teatro, dança e uma série de outras brincadeiras movimentaram o domingo no parque
Criançada aproveitou o domingo nos brinquedos
Denise Waskow
denise.waskow@diariogaucho.com.br
Se existe algo que deixa toda mãe realizada é ver que o filho está feliz. E quem levou a prole neste domingo à Redenção ganhou esse presente para celebrar o Dia das Mães. 
Jogos de mesa, futebol, brinquedos infláveis, teatro, dança e uma série de outras brincadeiras movimentaram o domingo, em uma ação promovida pela Secretaria Municipal de Esporte, Recreação e Lazer da Capital. A gurizada aproveitou muito, e as mamães se emocionaram com a alegria deles.
<subtítulo>Diversão nos brinquedos</subtítulo>
Enquanto a pequena Amanda, três anos, criava coragem para descer no tobogã inflável, a mãe, a babá Roselaine Pereira, 30 anos, ficava na parte de baixo do brinquedo, incentivando a menina a descer, fotografando e se divertindo junto.  
- É maravilhoso, é ótimo. O melhor presente é isso, a felicidade deles - derrete-se.
O filho mais velho, Jhonattan, 13 anos, já não está mais na fase de brincar, mas nem por isso deixou de acompanhar a mãe. Enquanto a irmã caçula passava de um brinquedo para o outro, ele contou como homenageou Roselaine no início do domingo: 
- Eu disse que eu amo ela.
<subtítulo>Uma torcida especial</subtítulo>
"Vai Joana, vai Joana!". Ao lado do espaço demarcado para o futebol, a massoterapeuta Tânia Regina Horta, 46 anos, incentivava a filha caçula, de seis anos, no esporte. E apesar de a mãe ser gremista e a filha colorada, não existe rivalidade. O que conta nessa relação, claro, é o amor. 
- A mãe que está sendo homenageada e são os filhos que se divertem. Está ótimo, o melhor é curtir a companhia deles - elogia. 
Depois de uma manhã inteira de brincadeiras, o planejamento de Tânia era encontrar os dois filhos mais velhos, além dos dois enteados, para o tradicional almoço de Dia das Mães.
</body>

TEXTO2
<head> <edic><Diário Gaúcho 14/05/2013</edic>
<autor></autor>
</head>
<body>
<subtítulo>Colisão</subtítulo>
<título>Sargento dos Bombeiros morre em acidente na zona sul da Capital</título>
Itiberê Poty de Abreu perdeu o controle da moto após colidir com um carro
Trânsito ficou em meia pista na Avenida Wenceslau Escobar
Um motociclista morreu após colidir hoje com um carro na Avenida Wenceslau Escobar, na zona sul de Porto Alegre. Itiberê Poty de Abreu, 49 anos, era sargento do Corpo de Bombeiros.
A vítima subia a avenida quando colidiu com o carro da frente e perdeu o controle da moto. Um outro veículo que trafegava no sentido contrário não conseguiu desviar e também se envolveu no acidente. O motociclista morreu no local.
O trânsito ficou em meia pista na Avenida Wenceslau Escobar e seria liberado após a remoção da vítima.
</body>
```

Eles começam com `TEXTO1(2, ...)` e terminam com o `/body`.

É possível separar eles em `arrays` diferentes? Se possível, como separar e fazer com que ele vá criando os `arrays`?

```
<?PHP

Array1 = "vai estar o texto01";
Array2 = "vai estar o texto02";
....
?>
```

Comment: Por que `arrays` e não duas `strings` ou um `array` com duas `strings`?

Comment: Pois estou trabalhando com arquivos de textos diferentes, onde cada arquivo possui entre 60 / 130 textos com a mesma formatação. Assim, a maneira mais fácil que encontrei para trabalhar foram os arrays.

Comment: A questão não é utilizar array ou não, mas sim caso você esteja pensando em algo diferente disto: `array('texto1' => 'Texto...', 'texto2' => 'Text...', ...);`, então sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente.

Comment: Na verdade, era nesse conceito que você mostrou que eu gostaria de fazer. Mas se caso for assim, é possível verificar o conteúdo que está no 'texto1'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é usar a função [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php) em conjunto com a expressão `|texto\d+(.+?)<\/body>|is` para obter o conteúdo que estiver entre `texto` seguido de um número e `</body>`, o modificador `i` é para não diferenciar letras minúsculas e maiúsculas, e `s` é para indicar que o `.` também pode capturar nova linha.

```
preg_match_all('|texto\d+(.+?)<\/body>|is', $conteudo, $resultado);
$textos = $resultado[1];
```

Onde a variável `conteudo` contém os textos que você quer separar.

Se você quiser acessar o primeiro texto por exemplo, use `textos[0]`, o segundo `textos[1]` e assim por diante.

Para acessar o texto indicando a chave, como o [Kenny Rafael sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159407/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-array-php#comment328081_159407), você pode fazer assim:

```
preg_match_all('|texto\d+(.+?)<\/body>|is', $conteudo, $resultado);
$textos = [];

foreach ($resultado[1] as $indice => $texto) {
    $textos["texto$indice"] = explode("\n", $texto);
}

foreach ($textos['texto1'] as $linha) { // Acessando as linhas do texto1
    echo $linha . "\n";
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/YQjS06)</kbd>